# Does Kernel.caller (or $@) work in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Do the following populate in production?

```
Kernel.caller
$@
```

I am trying to retrieve the backtrace for monitoring apps, and I can verify those both work in development mode, but can't be certain they don't work in production (easy to test in development, but in production I am sending the backtrace to an outside app).

Or, is there something else I can call to get the backtrace or enable it to work? I understand how to enable logging, but I can't be certain that necessarily effects the backtrace.

..removed un-needed code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to enable anything, it just works, this is not related to `rails` at all, it's just a `ruby` feature.

Comment: If the method [`caller`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/caller) is defined for Ruby, it's available in any environment. It's only extensions that may or may not be present.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Any reason either would not be available in where I am accessing it (I updated my question with the code..)?

Comment: Found my problem. The solution is as simple as this solution states. Thanks.